# Kafka : ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, classcastexception, confluent-schema-registry

I have this exception in the consumer when trying to cast the record.value() into java object :

```
ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast  to class [...].PublicActivityRecord (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record and [...].PublicActivityRecord are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The **producer** sends the java object, which is a user defined type named `PublicActivityRecord`, like this :

```java
KafkaProducer<String, PublicActivityRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(createKafkaProperties());

[...]

    this.producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, PublicActivityRecord>(myTopic, activityRecord));
    this.producer.flush();
```

At this point I can see in debug mode that the value of the `ProducerRecord` is indeed of type `PublicActivityRecord`.

On the registry server I can see in the log the POST request of the producer sending the schema :

```
Registering new schema: subject DEV-INF_9325_activityRecord_01-value, version null, id null, type null, schema size 7294 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource:262)
[2022-01-28 07:01:35,575] INFO 192.168.36.30 - - [28/janv./2022:06:01:34 +0000] "POST /subjects/DEV-INF_9325_activityRecord_01-value/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8 "-" "Java/11.0.2" POSTsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
```

On the **consumer** side :

```java
protected KafkaConsumer<String, PublicActivityRecord> consumer;

[...]

consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties);
consumer.subscribe(Stream.of(kafkaConfig.getTopicActivityRecord()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
final ConsumerRecords<String, PublicActivityRecord> records = consumer.poll(duration);
records.forEach(record -> {

    [...]

    PublicActivityRecord activityRecord = record.value();
```

Here the ClassCastException occurs.

In debug mode, I can see that the `record.value` is indeed of type `GenericData$Record`. And it can not be cast to PublicActivityRecord.

The serializer/deserilizer keys and values are the same :

```
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

And in the schema-registry log, I can see the GET request of the consumer :

```
"GET /schemas/ids/3?fetchMaxId=false HTTP/1.1" 200 8447 "-" "Java/11.0.7" GETsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
```

So I have checked that :

1. the producer sends a message with my own type `PublicActivityRecord`
2. the message is received in the kafka broker
3. the producer posts the schema to the schema registry
4. the message is taken by the consumer
5. the schema is GET by the consumer from the schema registry
6. the value of the message is of the unexpected `GenericData$Record`

This leads me to the result that what is wrong is in my consumer.

So the question is : Why do the consumer get a `GenericData` record instead of the expected `PublicActivityRecord` ?

Any clue would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, only generic records are returned. You'll need to set

```
value.deserializer.specific.avro.reader=true
```

Or, use the constant in your consumer configs

`KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG` = true

Comment: thanks for the hint, it helped me significantly. You have to set the mentioned config in your Spring Boot application as follows:
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
      properties:
        specific:
          avro:
            reader: true

Comment: @Dany Consumer deserializer properties shouldn't be broken apart. `specific.avro.reader: true`  should be on one line

Answer (score 0):

We got the same error by deserializing Kafka records with AVRO in Apache Flink. The cause was that we had renamed the namespaces of the POJO objects generated by the AVRO tools. So the namespace of the schema and the POJO object differed.